# Control Characters issues while Uploading Data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, special-characters

Trying to upload the data in PostgreSQL by using the query:

```
COPY "nad_data" FROM 'D:\NAD_Files\NAD.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV header 
encoding 'utf8';

COPY "nad_data" FROM 'D:\NAD_Files\NAD.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' quote e'\b' CSV 
header encoding 'utf8';

COPY "nad_data" FROM 'D:\NAD_Files\NAD.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' quote e'\b' CSV 
header encoding 'win-1252';
```

Every time I came up with this error:

> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
>   CONTEXT:  COPY nad_data, line 10314533: "14879314 Tennessee   McMinn
>        Athens     37303                               County Rd 3051
>        579

This line basically contains some control characters. Like this

[image]

These special or control characters are causing a problem.

Any suggestions how to handle them or remove them from data ?

Comment: yeah, line 4 looks particularly bad,  what format is that data supposed to be?

Comment: this is a tab-separated data.

Comment: is there an escape character?  and if so, what is it?

Comment: Try replacing "\" with "\\" in all records and see what you get.

Comment: what are those blue arrows?